# How to find Post Which has more than one Comments in rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Post
 has_many :comments
end

class Comment
 belongs_to :post
end
```

How to find Post Which has more than one Comments in rails query?

Comment: If my answer resolved my issue, you can accept it so it will help other user in future

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below query should work

```
Post.joins(:comments).group('posts.id').having('count(comments.id) > ?', 1)
```

Comment: Yup, thought same but little correction was needed! +1 Your answer serves what I was trying to do so deleted mine

Answer (score 6):

Most elegant way is to use rails [counter-cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

The first thing you have to do is, add `comments_count` column to the `Post` model & add following in `Comment` model,

```
belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
```

So you can obtain posts with comments greater than 1 as below,

```
Post.where('comments_count > ?', 1)
```

This is **rail-ish** way to have implementation.

Comment: I've upvoted this as the most appropriate Rails solution. Makes sense to use the correct tool for the job, while resulting in an efficient query.